# Clearing MOST labels on form, NOT all

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net-3.5

I need to clear 32 labels on my windows form application, there are other labels present but I do **NOT** want to clear these. Is there a more efficient and less coded way to do this? My code for this at the moment is as follows using a method: (snippet)

```
private void ClearFields()
{
    label50.Text = string.Empty;
    label51.Text = string.Empty;
    label52.Text = string.Empty;
    label53.Text = string.Empty;
    label54.Text = string.Empty;
    label55.Text = string.Empty;
    // Down to label82
}
```

I have researched but it's always clearing **ALL** labels/textboxes.

Comment: are the labels all in the same panel? Then you could loop the children of the panel and check if the name is between label50 and label82. But that would not be efficient.

Comment: Whatever you do is going to come down to identifying the difference between the ones to clear, and the ones to leave alone.  All the answers resolve down to this.  Pick the option that is _least likely to change_ over time.  Meaning avoid things you might alter, which would break your "search" logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an object to the `Tag` of the `Label` you want to clear.

```
Label label50 = new Label();
bool deleteMe = true;
label50.Tag = deleteMe;
```

Then just iterate over your labels and clear all where the `Tag` is `true`:

```
foreach(Label lbl in myLabels)
{
    if(lbl.Tag != null && lbl.Tag is bool && (bool)lbl.Tag == true)
    {
        lbl.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following line:

```
foreach (Label _label in this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(a => a.Name != "Lable32").Select(a => a).ToArray())
            _label.Text = string.Empty;
```

Add non removal lable in where condition if there are many. Here except `lable32` all lable text will set to empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to place all the labels that need to be cleared in some kind of cointainer. That way you can do something of the sort:

```
foreach (var child in container.Children)
{
    if (child is Label)
    {
        ((Label)child).Text=String.Empty;
    }
}
```

I am not very familiar with WinForms, but I think there are containers there.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Tag` property of the labels you do not want cleared to the string `"DoNotClear"` (using the Property Window or code) then use the following LINQ code:

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Tag != "DoNotClear"))
    label.Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**  you can use `Controls.Find()` method to find the controls from id `label50` to `label82` and assign `String.Empty` for each identified Label.

Try This:

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i=50;i<83;i++)
            {
                this.Controls.Find("label" + i,true)[0].Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your labels have names like `label + id`

```
var labelsToClear = from l in Controls.OfType<Label>()
                    let id = Int32.Parse(l.Name.Replace("label", "")) 
                    where id >= 50 && id <= 82
                    select l;

foreach(var label in labelsToClear)
   label.Text = String.Empty;
```

If labels can have different names, then you can filter out labels which match `label + id` pattern:

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => Regex.IsMatch(l.Name, @"^(?:label)\d+$"))
```